# Trying to add different variables with values to a small string of program C++

Tags: c++

im having a project at school where we were supposed to create a short code and i tried something new and ended up with this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

int main() 
{
    const double A =10.25, B = 15.75, C = 13.25, D = 9.75;
    std::string line = "";
    double sum = 0.0;
    double price;
    while (line != "T") 
    {
        std::cout << "please enter item ordered [A/B/C/D] or \"T\" to calculate total: " << std::endl;
        std::cout << "current sum : " << sum << std::endl;
        std::cin >> line;
        sum += atof(line.c_str());
    }
    price = sum + (sum * .06);
    std::cout << "please pay this amount: $" << price << std::endl;
}
```

It's supposed to ask a question, then take the amount and add all the orders (a, b, c, d) and then add a tax of 6%. i tried making then as int but that didnt seem to make a difference.

I can't seem to get the different variables to hold a number. is there something I can do or should I attempt a strategy?

thanks in advace

Comment: `double itemValue[ ] = {10.25, 15.75, 13.25, 9.75};` -- Start with that, i.e., learn how to use an array, not 4 separate variables.

Comment: This line is wrong: sum += atof(line.c_str());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your prompt implies that user would type `A`, `B`, etc., but the code later treats it as floating point value (`sum += atof(line.c_str());`).

If you type a value, like `10.25` into you program, and end with letter `T` - it would work.

Probably, not what you intended.

You can use `if-else` statements to see if `A` or `B` was entered, then add a value of one of your variables to the `sum`.

Answer (score 0):

If you change your line to "char" instead of "string" and use array, then it will work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    const double products[4] = {10.25, 15.75, 13.25, 9.75}; //A-10.25, B-15.75, C-13.25, D-9.75
    char line = '-';
    double sum = 0.0;
    double price;
    while (line != 'T')
    {
        std::cout << "please enter item ordered [A/B/C/D] or \"T\" to calculate total: " << std::endl;
        std::cout << "current sum : " << sum << std::endl;
        std::cin >> line;
        sum += products[ int(line-'A') ];
    }
    price = sum + (sum * .06);
    std::cout << "please pay this amount: $" << price << std::endl;
}
```

line is a char, so
`std::cin >> line;` will read character, then
`int(character)` returns the number as the ASCII table goes (google if you don't know what that is), for example character A has number 65, B has 66, C 67 and so on. int(line-'A') returns 0 for line=A, 1 for B, 2 for C etc.

Answer (score 0):

In the above code you get A,B,C,D strings as console inputs.

You are trying add these string values to the sum. Because  **atof(line.c_str())** only converts string value to the double value.
Ex:string "1" converts to double 1.0

Instead you should add price values correspond to these strings.
Ex:If input value is "A" then add 10.25
If input value is "B" then add 15.75

Use a switch case to check the user input as follow.
Further use char instead of string since A,B,C,D and T are all characters.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main() 
{
const double A =10.25, B = 15.75, C = 13.25, D = 9.75;
char line = ' ';
double sum = 0.0;
double price;

while (line != 'T') 
{
    std::cout << "please enter item ordered [A/B/C/D] or \"T\" to calculate total: " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "current sum : " << sum << std::endl;
    std::cin >> line;

    switch(line){
    case('A'):{

        sum += A;
        break;
        
    }
    case('B'):{

        sum += B;
        break;
        
    }
    case('C'):{

        sum += C;
        break;
        
    }
    case('D'):{

        sum += D;
        break;
        
    }
    case('T'):{
    
        break;
        
    }
    default:{

           break;
     }

    }
  
  }

    price = sum + (sum * .06);
    std::cout << "please pay this amount: $" << price << std::endl;
}
```